# Handling markdown's return characters in JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, markdown

I have a dict represented as follows in a file.

```
{"title" : "My Test Document", "tags" : "tag1, tag2",

"body" : "## My Test Document

Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country. 

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back."

}
```

The value of "body" is formatted as markdown.

When I execute this code --

```
f = 'my_file.txt'
data = json.load(open(f))
```

-- I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 3 column 30 (char 84)
```

Presumably this has to do with JSON's handling of return characters. Is there a good way to handle these characters in JSON such that the integrity of the markdown is maintained? Is there a better way to work with this file than JSON? I need to be able to create these files manually and work with them as dicts programmatically. Everything else is optional.

UPDATE:

Eventually I will have a machine process that formats these files before saving them. Until then, this is the least complicated hack I could produce:

```
str=myfile.read().replace('\n', '\\n')
str = str.replace("\\n\\n\"body\"", " \"body\"")
```

My preference would be a format that plays well with new lines. Pickle proved even more difficult to work with than JSON. Going to leave this open in case anyone has a less hackish solution.

Comment: that is illegal json ... how is it being generated... that is the likely culprit and should be resolved rather than forcing something that is not json to be json ...

Comment: It's being created manually in a text editor. If I remove the markdown, it works fine.

Comment: use `\n` for newlines instead of enter(when within a string) ...

Comment: Putting in \n while creating these files is not viable. I attempted converting them prior to json.load, but could still not get this file to play well with json.

Comment: There's a few different things going on here- I think it would be good to walk back a few steps. Where are you expecting to get this badly formatted JSON from? If the content of `'body'` comes from a text file, then you can replace `\n` characters when reading in that file, but you can't replace all `\n` characters in your final JSON file, you only want to be replacing within the `body` section.

Comment: I have already said, these files will be manually created. As I have also said, the JSON load works fine when the markdown is removed. I am aware that the newlines have to be replaced. I am not able to figure the right way to do it, per the last example in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really insist on doing it this way

```
 my_text = open("some_text.json").read()
 split1 = my_text.split('body" :')
 fixed_body = split1[-1].rsplit('"',1)[0].replace("\n","\\n")
 fixed_text = split1[0] + 'body" :' + fixed_body + '"}'
 d =json.loads(fixed_text)
```

but its a horrible hack the right way is to generate correct json ...

marginally better is to manually parse it with `re`

```
 my_text = open("some_text.json").read().strip("{}")
 d = dict((k,v) for k,v in re.findall('"([^"]+)" : "([^"]+)"',my_text))
 print d
```

however this is still pretty hacky ...

**update since OP is not tied to JSON**

I suppose the real answer is to use YAML instead of JSON

```
easy_install pyyaml
```

.

```
 import yaml
 print yaml.load(open("some_text.json").read())
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a format for handling data in files that is less finicky about new lines. As I said, I don't have to use JSON. I am unwilling to use \n characters when producing these files instead of using returns.

Comment: @MikeGirard see response if you are not tied to json

Comment: This is less of a hack certainly, since the YAML spec specifically has syntax for preserving new lines, which are collapsed by default. This syntax makes producing the markdown snippet more time consuming, depending on the text editor. I may continue with my hack, but this is a better answer simply because it's conformant with the spec.

Answer (score 0):

For this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

You can use `json.loads` instead of `json.load` to avoid it.

Since `json.load` accept a file-like object as parameter and `json.loads` accept a `str` or `unicode` instance as parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out, but when I fix that another error gets triggered due to the markdown. Thanks, though.